# Why does this WHERE clause work in my MyBatis mapper + Spring3 application?

Tags: java, spring, mybatis

I found the below code in an example and it works. But I don't know why.

My questions are:

- How does the mapping from `getDrugsWithAlert(int count)` get assigned to `#{maxrowcount}` (I can put anything inside: `#{maxrowcount}`, `#{mcount}` and it does not seem to matter);
- how/why the `if test="_parameter != null and _parameter > 0` works?

My DAO interface looks like this:

```
@Repository
public interface DrugMasterDao {
    public List<Drug_Master> getDrugsWithAlert(int count);
}
```

My mapper file looks like this:

```
<mapper namespace="org.mydb.formulary.drugmaster.dao.DrugMasterDao">

    <select id="getDrugsWithAlert" parameterType="int"  
            resultType="org.mydb.formulary.drug_master.model.Drug_Master">

        Select drug_id , drug_name , drug_alert_date, drug_alert_source
          from (select drug_id,drug_name,to_char(drug_alert_datetime,'MM/DD/YYYY') as
                       drug_alert_date ,drug_alert_source
                  from drug_master
                  where drug_status ='A' and length(drug_alert) > 0
                  order by drug_alert_datetime DESC )

       <if test="_parameter != null and _parameter > 0">
          where rownum &lt;= #{maxrowcount}
       </if>
    </select>
 </mapper>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your queries have declared [parameters](http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#Parameters) that will be replaced with their corresponding values upon execution. The parameter names are properties on the object that you send to the query.

But your mapping has `parameterType="int"` which is a simple value. The value will replace the parameter entirely. If your parameter type is a `Map` or object of some sort then the names become important because they name the keys or properties of the object, respectively.

Because you have an `int` the name is unimportant and can be `#{maxrowcount}`, `#{mcount}`, `#{whatever}`. That's why the first part works.

For the second part it's trickier because `_parameter` is [undocumented](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/issues/detail?id=245). MyBatis is a nice framework but, sadly, lacks on the documentation part. The input parameter is stored under the key `_parameter` in the mapping context. In this case it's your `int` parameter. That's how the second part works.